# Oracle 12.2 Pro*C - Visual Studio 2015 C++ Warning - Declaration of sqlstm hides global declaration

Tags: windows, oracle, visual-c++

**Environment:**

Win10 64bit
Visual Studio 2015 with update 3
Oracle 12.2 64bit client with Pro*C

The *.cpp file generated from the *.pc file is generating the following warning

This is a automatically generated file by Pro*C from *.pc file. Both the original struct and struct within the function1() have been automatically generated.

```
//generated by pro*c
static struct sqlexd {
param1
param2
...
} sqlstm  {13,2}


int function1 ()
{
  struct sqlexd sqlstm;  //hides global sqlstm from above
  sqlstm.slvsn = 13
  sqlstm.arrsiz = 2
}
```

```
struct sqlexd sqlstm; //this causes a C4459 warning
```

**C4459 declaration of slqstm hides global declaration**

The cpp file is automatically generated by the *.pc file. I'm not quite sure how to resolve this warning as it's a auto-generated file

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to SO. Consider reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask